# How to use the instantaneous request controller pattern in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use [this pattern](https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/beyond-mock-objects) to write reproducible tests which check that the date given by the user is in the future, but I can't quite fit my head around how it would work in Django. What I'm trying to do is as follows:

1. I have a model with a `DateTimeField`, which when created must verify that the field value is in the future. That is, if the value is in the past, it should throw a `ValidationError`.
2. Obviously, when running in production the code should use the actual current time.
3. The tests *must* inject the current time into whatever they are calling to ensure that the test is reproducible.

What would be an idiomatic way of doing this using the Django REST Framework? I've come up with a few possibilities, none of which work:

1. Create a plain model subclass of the model with `instant = models.DateTimeField()`. This of course would result in another table and column, which is unacceptable.
2. Create a proxy model subclass of the model with `instant = models.DateTimeField()`. It's not possible to add fields to proxy models, so that's out.
3. Create a serializer wrapper class like this:

   ```
   class InstantaneousModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       def __init__(self, serializer, *args, **kwargs):
           self.serializer = serializer
           [Copy every relevant attribute from self.serializer to self]
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def validate_start(self, value):
           self.serializer.instant = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
           return self.serializer.validate_start(value)
   ```

   I can now refer to `self.instant` in the inner serializer, but this solution has several issues:

   1. I now need to wrap all the time (because the `instant` field is only defined in the wrapper class), which is at least as bad as injecting a clock.
   2. Having to copy `Meta`, any validators, etc. is terrible.

---

The code so far (without any datetime injection):

- tests.py:

  ```
  def test_should_not_allow_setting_start_datetime_in_the_past(self):
      serializer = MySerializer(
          data={
              […]
              'start': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
          }
      )
      with self.assertRaisesMessage(ValidationError, 'Start cannot be in the past'):
          serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  ```
- serializers.py:

  ```
  class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      […]
      def validate_start(self, value):
          if value < datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc):
              raise ValidationError({'start': 'Start cannot be in the past'})
          return value
  ```

---

One half-way solution would be to use [serializer context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

- In `test_should_not_allow_setting_start_datetime_in_the_past`:

  ```
  serializer = serializers.MySerializer(
      data={
          […]
          'start': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
      context={'now': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, second=1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
  )
  ```
- In `validate_start`:

  ```
  instant = self.context.get('now', datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
  ```

Not reusable, and the resulting validator code still references an unstable dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "now" method to your serialiser and mock that function in your tests.  This essentially creates a proxy to the datetime method on your serializer for the sake of tests.

serializers.py

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def now(self):
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

    def validate_start(self, value):
        if value < self.now():
            raise ValidationError({'start': 'Start cannot be in the past'})
        return value
```

tests.py

```
def test_should_not_allow_setting_start_datetime_in_the_past(self):
    serializer = MySerializer(
        data={
            'start': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
        }
    )
    with self.assertRaisesMessage(
        ValidationError, 'Start cannot be in the past'
    ), mock.patch(
        "app.serializers.MySerializer.now"
    ) as now:
        now.return_value = datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```